# How could I upload an icon I made in Adobe Illustrator to my HTML document?

Tags: javascript, html, css, icons

I can export the file as an SVG, but how would I actually customize it with a hover effect afterwards? I use FontAwesome for most of my icons, but I'm not sure how I'd get my own icon to carry the `<i>` tag so that I could modify it the same way as the others.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do something like this:

Possibly, you can use SVG in an ordinary IMG tag:

https://caniuse.com/svg-img

`<img src="/static/image.svg">`

You can then add event handlers to the icon:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events

I believe it's supported now.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the svg that you've exported.and when you want to hover it and change the color you can change the "fill" of the svg o path tag!

```css
svg:hover path{
  fill:blue;
}
```

```html
<svg fill="red" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="26.484" height="26.484" viewBox="0 0 26.484 26.484">
  <path id="price-tag" d="M26.484,5.206,21.266,0H14.692L12.1,2.583A19.584,19.584,0,0,0,.391,5.721a.469.469,0,1,0,.546.763A18.724,18.724,0,0,1,11.209,3.471L2.816,11.837l0,0L0,14.653,11.805,26.484l4.713-4.7a6.965,6.965,0,0,0,3.208.756A6.1,6.1,0,0,0,24,20.988a7.184,7.184,0,0,0,1.616-8.278l.868-.866V5.206ZM20.878.939,25.545,5.6v5.859L16.373,20.6c-1.917-1.375-2.5-3.954-1.64-7.336a.469.469,0,1,0-.91-.232c-1.215,4.773.418,7.127,1.877,8.238L14.624,22.34,4.148,11.842l8.3-8.278a14.369,14.369,0,0,1,6.125,2.191,1.824,1.824,0,0,0-.032.318A1.871,1.871,0,1,0,18.974,4.9a15.291,15.291,0,0,0-5.689-2.17L15.08.939ZM19.63,6.479a.469.469,0,1,0,.563-.751c-.145-.108-.291-.2-.436-.306a.907.907,0,1,1-.207,1C19.577,6.442,19.6,6.458,19.63,6.479Zm-18.3,8.177,2.156-2.15,10.479,10.5-2.156,2.15Zm22.008,5.669a5.881,5.881,0,0,1-6.117.761l7.687-7.667A6.168,6.168,0,0,1,23.336,20.324Z" fill="red"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: How would I get that code from my SVG file? I've never seen many of those tags before. =(

Comment: open your svg file in a browser the right click in the screen and click on "view page source" then you can see the code of your svg file and you can copy it and use it as I used here.

Answer (score 1):

in your CSS you should access the SVG tag then instead of color use fill for SVG than in your HTML just have your SVG tag.

```css
svg:hover{
fill:red;
}
```

```html
<svg id="Layer_1" enable-background="new 0 0 512.843 512.843" height="512" viewBox="0 0 512.843 512.843" width="512" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="m398.254 492.44c0 11.046-8.954 20-20 20s-20-8.954-20-20 8.954-20 20-20 20 8.954 20 20zm-288-19.964c-11.028 0-20-8.972-20-20v-246.489l166-151.439 166 151.439v72.147c13.732 3.002 27.121 7.419 40 13.19v-48.846l23.296 21.252 26.958-29.55-256.254-233.776-256.254 233.776 26.958 29.55 23.296-21.252v209.998c0 33.084 26.916 59.964 60 59.964h208.744l-39.957-39.964zm268-83.036c-24.131 0-50.247 11.167-68.241 29.143l-14.15 14.135 28.269 28.299 14.15-14.134c10.607-10.597 27.261-17.442 40.972-17.442 13.55 0 29.168 6.847 39.775 17.442l14.15 14.134 28.269-28.299-14.15-14.135c-17.996-17.977-45.074-29.143-69.044-29.143zm120.486-24.825c-32.822-33.002-75.379-51.177-119.833-51.176-44.463.001-87.021 18.176-119.834 51.178l-14.103 14.183 28.365 28.203 14.102-14.183c25.25-25.394 57.734-39.38 91.47-39.381 33.728-.001 66.213 13.985 91.471 39.383l14.103 14.181 28.362-28.207z"/></svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it to a PNG or JPEG, and then place it into your HTML document.

```html
 <!-- Use it as an image  ╌>
<img src="/image.png>`
 <!-- or as a website favicon  ╌>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico"/>
```

To convert the file types you can use an online converter or the command line.